# Can't create stored procedure: Syntax error

Tags: mysql, procedure

I want to make a procedure that will insert user in table, but it should also check if user is 18 years old. I'm "doing" it with an `if` statement (`p_datum_rodjenja` is birth date of user). I'm not sure if my logic works because I cant create this procedure: when I try to run the query I got the following error:

> Syntax error. Error code:1064.

Here is my code:

```
delimiter #
create  procedure dodajKorisnikaProvjera
(
    IN p_ime varchar(15),
    IN p_prezime varchar(15),
    IN p_broj_telefona int,
    IN p_datum_rodjenja date,
    IN p_broj_vozacke int,
    IN p_grad_id int
)
BEGIN

if(TIMESTAMPDIFF(p_datum_rodjenja,CURDATE()) >18) then

    INSERT into korisnik(
    ime,
    prezime,
    broj_telefona,
    datum_rodjenja,
    broj_vozacke,
    grad_id)
     VALUES(
    p_ime,
    p_prezime,
    p_broj_telefona,
    p_datum_rodjenja,
    p_broj_vozacke,
    p_grad_id
    );
    else
    select'Korisnik mora imati vise od 18 godina.';
    end if;

END#
delimiter;
```

Comment: Correct if condition like this: (TIMESTAMPDIFF(year,p_datum_rodjenja,CURDATE()) >18)

Comment: Thx dude,it works. If u only could help me what is that "year", why i use it?

Comment: Here is the good tutorial on this:  http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timestampdiff-function.php

Comment: Thx, now i get it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having error in Timestampdiff function.
Correct out it like this:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(year,p_datum_rodjenja,CURDATE()) >18)
```